# JsTree checkbox - check event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have this JsTree

[image]

with this code:

```
var Tree = $("#MyTree");

        Tree.jstree({
            "core": {
                "themes": {
                    "responsive": false,
                    "multiple" : false,
                },
                "data": dataTree
            },
            "types": {
                "default": {
                    "icon": "icon-lg"
                },
                "file": {
                    "icon": "icon-lg"
                }
            },
            "ui": {
                "select_limit": 1,
            },
            "plugins": ["wholerow", "types", "checkbox", "ui", "crrm", "sort"],
            "checkbox": {
                "three_state": false,
                "real_checkboxes": false
            }
        });
```

I need to separate the selection and the check action, the user must check all node he wants but select only one row for time.
for now when I click everywhere on the row it select that row and check that node, i need to check the checkbox only if the user click on it.

I try so much event but the only that work is:

```
Tree.on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) { });
```

that catch both the action of selection and check.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This answer is about the release 3 of jstree - that is what you should use in year 2016. Unfortunaltely your sample code, seems using jstree rel 1, and I can't help you about that.

**For release 3**

First of all, untie the selected and the checked states (checkbox.tie_selection: false) - see [the docs](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=$.jstree.defaults.checkbox&f=$.jstree.defaults.checkbox.tie_selection)

Then, use the `check_node.jstree` event

**Working example**

```js
var data1 = [{
      "id": "W",
      "text": "World",
      "state": { "opened": true },
      "children": [{"text": "Asia"}, 
                   {"text": "Africa"}, 
                   {"text": "Europe",
                    "state": { "opened": false },
                    "children": [ "France","Germany","UK" ]
      }]
    }];

$('#Tree').jstree({ 
    core: {
      data: data1, 
      check_callback: false
    }, 
    checkbox: {       
      three_state : false, // to avoid that fact that checking a node also check others
      whole_node : false,  // to avoid checking the box just clicking the node 
      tie_selection : false // for checking without selecting and selecting without checking
    },
    plugins: ['checkbox']
})
.on("check_node.jstree uncheck_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
  alert(data.node.id + ' ' + data.node.text +
        (data.node.state.checked ? ' CHECKED': ' NOT CHECKED'))
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <div id="Tree"></div>
```

Comment: I downloaded jstree 3.2.1, the snippet is exactly what I have to do but it doesn't work in my solution... 
in my solution it doesn't add the check when I click the box but add it when I select the row

Comment: @LorenzoGrossi review your creation parameters. Particularly the `checkbox` section.

Comment: I copy and paste you snippet but it doesn't work anyway... It show the alert when I click the box and identify the event (check or uncheck), but it don't add the check symbol and add it when I select the row –

Comment: @LorenzoGrossi the code i posted works... why don't you post *your* code (update your question), so we can check what is wrong with it